# Can't detect collapse of bootstrap accordion using d3 selector

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

Is there any way to select a bootstrap accordion with a d3 selector and still have access to 'show.bs.collapse'

I tried using the d3 .classed() to look for 'collapse in' but the call back function can only return the name of the new class so I can't call any event.
Any thoughts?Thank's!

my code:

```
 d3.select('.panel-collapse')
   .on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        //do stuff
 })
```